# Windows Live Connect SDK Desktop walkthrough

Tags: .net

I'm having significant difficulty getting started with the Windows Live Connect SDK in a traditional Windows Form App.

I would like to know:

1. What SDK Package to install, and how to add a reference to my project?
2. A simple code sample, just the most basic example of how to authenticate.

From here I should be able to work out the rest, the online documentation is mainly for Windows 8 metro apps, or Windows phone.

Hopefully a more traditional wrapped assembly exists?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of fishing and getting bad references I came across this page:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/messengerconnect/thread/13566fdc-592d-493e-81c7-40b724136a4e/

The SDK only works on Windows 8 or Windows Phone. It is possible to use the REST services directly through, but obviously this is a steeper learning curve.

Answer (score 1):

you can find interessant article here on msdn

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243641.aspx

The APIs are downloaded here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/live/ff621310.aspx

Comment: Thanks it jumps right in to code samples, private LiveAuthClient auth; is what I'm looking for, how to add the required reference?

Comment: Thanks again Aghilas, it seems that the Windows Phone API might just work for desktop environments too. Got the reference. Now need to a test to see if authentication works.

Comment: Happy to help you JL, i added APIs to the post